# Active Anchor Link Colour Change On The Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a single page website which has large divs as a section/page. I have managed to get the anchors to work etc however the problem I am having is that the CSS `a:active` does not work in this scenario because the actual div is not linked to the anchor link at the top.
There is a span above each div which is the height of the header so that the sections do not get hidden behind it.

I was wondering if there is any way (using CSS/JavaScript) to get the anchor links to change color by themselves when the user is on a specific section of the page.

A similar example is on [**this web page**](http://smokeybones.com/) if someone wants to see it, this site actually uses an indicator rather than changing the links color. However I'm sure they're using JS because when I do inspect element in Google Chrome, as the indicator moves the CSS also changes position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can.

```
$('#specific-section').bind('mouseenter', function(){
  $('a').css('color','yellow');
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){
  $('a').css('color','white');
});
```